# Measurement of actual carbon dioxide mass emitted from a diesel engine

Tags: carbon-dioxide, emission

I was wondering if there is a method to measure the actual total mass of carbon dioxide $(\ce{CO2})$ emitted from a diesel engine used for power generation. Infrared $\ce{CO2}$ sensors generally measure the gas concentration, describing the amount of gas by volume in the air, which is not useful in my application. Flow sensors are already installed in the diesel supply and return lines to determine the amount of diesel consumed, and hence the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ created, but I need to correlate these measurements with actual measurements of $\ce{CO2}$ mass produced at the output of the exhaust system.

Any idea on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

The question can be reformulated as to measure the $\ce{CO2}$ emission rate from the engine exhaust system. A typical solution in practice is to find a dedicated sensor or a monitoring system that does that.

Comment: RGA measurements of the exhaust would give you the relative concentrations, combined with a mass flow measurements gives you mass.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to conduct RGA and mass flow measurements in practice?

Comment: There are only a few possible products of burning diesel: CO2, CO, unburned fuel and particulates. Knowing how much fuel is burned is the most accurate way of assessing CO2 output as the others are not major products. But CO and CO2 are measurable in the exhaust (but less accurately) so you can at least triangulate the estimate made from fuel burned.

Comment: @matt_black: Would you please let me know how "CO and CO2 are measured in the exhaust"?
As I mentioned in the question, the consumed fuel is already being measured, and the CO2 being estimated knowing the amount of carbon per gallon of diesel. However, I am looking for a redundant accurate method to measure the gas mass emitted from the exhaust stack.

Comment: @AEW CO is routinely measured in car exhausts using standard meters during routine inspections mandated in many countries (in the UK cars older than 3 years have to have MOT tests and the measurement is part of those). So commercial devices specifically measuring CO are widely available. Commercial CO2 meters are also common and have been used to tune engine performance. Neither, though, are as accurate as measuring the amount of fuel burned.